# Ограничение по времени на исполнение асинхронных задач

Tags: c#, .net, асинхронность

Как я могу реализовать метод Execute, чтобы задачи стартовали не чаще, чем раз в секунду (одновременно они выполняться могут в любом количестве, но именно старт должен происходить не чаще 1 раза в секунду)

```
public class Program 
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => MyTask()).ToArray();
        await Execute(tasks);
    }

    public static async Task MyTask()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task started");
        await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(2000));
        Console.WriteLine("Task stopped");
    }

    public static async Task Execute(Task[] tasks)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: В таком виде - никак. делая `Select(x => MyTask()).ToArray()` ты запускаешь сразу все таски

Comment: Не перписывая код за пределами метода `Execute` никак. Вот же они у вас все одновременно стартуют `x => MyTask()` <-- вызов, старт.

Comment: Уберите `ToArray()`, далее `Task[] tasks` замените на `IEnumerable<Task> tasks`, внутри создайте, ну допустим, `foreach`, который будет пробегаться по таскам, тем самым запуская их, ну и внутри цикла ждите нужное время до следующей итерации (запуска таски), в конце делайте ожидание завершения всех таск если надо (`Task.WaitAll` или `Task.WhenAll`), получите то, что хотели. Все это кстати лучше обернуть в Producer/Consumer паттерн и передавать не `Task`, а отдельный объект, внутри которого будет условная `Task Run(){ ... }`, который уже и будет вызываться в нужный момент.

Answer (score 0):

По комментариям, как я понял, таска запускается сразу в момент создания. Поэтому задача может быть решена таким образом:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => MyTask(x));
        await Execute(tasks);
    }

    public static async Task MyTask(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Task {id} started");
        await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(3000));
        Console.WriteLine($"Task {id} stopped");
    }

    public static async Task Execute(IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
    {
        var lastStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        var enumerator = tasks.GetEnumerator();
        var startedTasks = new List<Task>();
        while (true)
        {
            if (lastStart.AddSeconds(1) > DateTime.Now)
            {
                await Task.Delay(5);
                continue;
            }
            lastStart = DateTime.Now;
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                break;
            }

            startedTasks.Add(enumerator.Current);
        }

        Task.WaitAll(startedTasks.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed");
    }
}
```